# python regular expression not evaluating with \b

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to do a simple boundary regular expressions substitution on strings with dashes, but they do not replace, why is that, do the dashes mean anything in regex?

Here is my actual attempt where f is the variable where i want to replace the string exact matches:

```
>>> import re
>>> f = "user-services-http-two user-services-http"
>>> re.sub(r'\buser-services-http\b', '32370', f)
'32370-two 32370'
```

How would i get the desired output of:

```
'user-services-http-two 32370'
```

My requirement is that i have to use re since i am using another module in python (massedit) later on in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
re.sub(r'\buser-services-http$', '32370', f)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

f = "user-services-http-two user-services-http"
re.sub('\\b(user-services-http$)', '32370', f)
```

edited based on your extra comment above - but its the same as PKumar  - it works for all your cases